# OpenGl Fragment shader for gradient with hotspots of colors?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, gradient, fragment-shader

I am very new to opengl, I am trying to recreate this effect

[image]

i.e. sort of a gradient between hardcoded colors where colors originate from  certain hardcoded positions

I do understand basic concepts, I have whipped up a demo of a linear gradient between two given colors, but thats obviously not enough.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

uniform float time;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;

float lerp(float start, float end, float fraction) {
    return start + ((end - start) * fraction);
}

void main( void ) {
    vec4 beginColor = vec4(0.21, 1.0, 0.78, 1.0);
    vec4 endColor = vec4(1.0, 0.48, 0.21, 1.0);
    vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;

    vec4 color = vec4(
        lerp(beginColor.x, endColor.x, position.x),
        lerp(beginColor.y, endColor.y, position.x),
        lerp(beginColor.z, endColor.z, position.x),
        1.0);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

How would be the technique to create those "sources" of color? Maybe multiple radial gradients blended together? (Probably not)

Comment: Not answering your question, but you can use the built-in "mix()" function, rather than writing a custom lerp.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do that in a pixel shader wholesale, if possible. Instead, I would place vertices with color at every color center, use [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) to create the faces  (everything until this point happens on the CPU) and  then render the mesh with just the most basic vertex color interpolation to get the end result.

If you really want to use only a pixel shader, then I guess you need to iterate all color centers, find the three closest ones to form a triangle, express the current location in barycentric coordinates in this triangle, and finally use the coordinates as weights to interpolate the three colors. This already seems like a bad idea, because you'd basically be duplicating all the work the GPU does for you anyway.